# Simple reordering function returning garbage

Tags: c++

As part of a larger program I'm writing, I am reordering a vector. The function is:

```
void reorderVector(vector<char> &sourceVector){
    int vectorSize = sourceVector.size();
    vector<char> vectorOrdered;

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++){
            vectorOrdered.push_back(sourceVector.back());
            sourceVector.pop_back();
    }
    sourceVector = vectorOrdered;
}
```

And the code I am using to test it is:

```
int main(){
    vector<char> testVector[10];
    int i;

    for( i=0; i< 10; i++){
        testVector[i] = 100-i;
    }

    reorderVector(testVector);
    int j=0;
    while( j<10){
        cout<< testVector[i]<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting this after compilation (with the c++ compiler):

```
functionTest.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
functionTest.cc:35: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘testVector[i] = (100 - i)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:156: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = char, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
functionTest.cc:38: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >&’ from a temporary of type ‘std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >*’
functionTest.cc:14: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void reorderVector(std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >&)’
functionTest.cc:41: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << testVector[i]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>
```

I don't know why is there a problem with operator (problem with the minus sign??). I am guessing there is a problem with the pointers? However I can't discern what it is. If it is of any help, I am compiling this code in an Amazon server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 vector<char> testVector[10];
```

This means that `testVector` is an array with size 10, each element of the array is a vector of `char`. It is "the same" (syntax-wise) as:

```
 int testVector[10];
 //assume that you add typedef vector<char> int;
```

You probably wants the following:

```
vector<char> testVector(10);
```

Another error in the code is you have a dead-loop (loop forever):

```
int j=0;
while( j<10){
cout<< testVector[i]<< endl; 
  //^^^you have to increment j here in order to exit the loop 
  //^^^and why testVector[i]???
}
```

Comment: It seems that I still have much to learn about vectors in c++ and programming in general. To be clear, if I wanted to access the ith element I would type `testVector(i)`, correct?

Comment: @FSB No, please check the documentation for std::vector. to access element, you can use `[]` operator, i.e., testVector[i].

Answer (score 0):

The error says

```
 no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘testVector[i] = (100 - i)’
```

Check that line. You can see that you declared your vector as array of vectors:

```
vector<char> testVector[10];
```

So the `=` operator wants to convert an `int` to a `vector`, that's not possible (without any overload).

It seems that instead of an array of 10 vectors, you wanted to create a vector of 10 elements and in that case you must ure

```
vector<char> testVector(10);
```

Note that I've used round parenthesis that define constructor arguments, while squared brackets are used for array.